# How to show alert dialog when multiple checkboxes are checked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I have two checkboxes, Now I want to show a alertdialog when both are checked and if only one is checked then I don't want to show user any info.

For this purpose I have created below code in oncreate but nothing is happening when run the application.

```
if (Percentage.isChecked()==true &&  Value.isChecked()==true)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder showdialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            showdialog.setTitle("Check Alert");
            showdialog.setMessage("You can't select both options");
            showdialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }

                
            });
            
            showdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
            });
            
            showdialog.show();
        }
```

Is my approach wrong? If so, what changes do I need to make to fix this?

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: for FSM sake just debug your code ... it is not working because in the time of running this code `Percentage.isChecked()==true &&  Value.isChecked()==true` is false and by `the time of running ...` i mean in the `onCreate` ... you have to move this code to some kind of event triggered after checkbox state has changed ...

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your response then In this case how can I capture the checked state and show the alertdialog.. It will be helpful if you can provide me the idea.. i am newbie to android

Comment: look into Checkbox docs, search for setOnSomthingListener where OnSomething you have to choose(depends on your needs) ... i don't have time for reading the docs for you but maybe onclick or onchecked or onselected or somthing similar

Comment: Thanks for your help @Selvin... just an idea is sufficient for me.. I can carry forward my work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved on my own... I'm answering so that anyone who has the same issue can use this.

Create one method to capture the checked state of the code:

```
public void showalert(){

        if (Percentage.isChecked()==true &&  Value.isChecked()==true)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder showdialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            showdialog.setTitle("Check Alert");
            showdialog.setMessage("You can't select both options");
            showdialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Percentage.setChecked(false);
                    Value.setChecked(false);
                }


            });

            showdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Percentage.setChecked(false);
                    Value.setChecked(false);
                }
            });

            showdialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Now for individual checkboxes invoked the method `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in that called the above created method.

```
Percentage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showalert();

            }
        });

        Value.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showalert();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hhhmm... that's odd, I didn't see `showdialog.create();` .